# Contact form doesn't display in cs-cart

Tags: php, cs-cart

CS-Cart 2.0.8
PHP 5.4

Our host is 1and1 and they are basically forcing us to move to PHP 5.4.  Once we did so, the Contact us form no longer displays on the page.

I know there are issues with PHP 5.4.  What are my options at this point?  I'd like to get this working without having to upgrade the store right now (though I am recommending that to the client).  Any advice?  Is there a fix or a workaround?

EDIT: we removed the contact form and replaced it with a mailto link.  No workaround at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cs-cart 2.0.8 does not support this version of cs-cart. It may cause many more problems, not only one that you describe. It would be better to downgrade your php version. It should be less then v5.3.0

Comment: Unfortunately, my client is currently hosted on 1&1 and they are forcing accounts to upgrade their PHP.  Is upgrading cs-cart a difficult proposition?

Comment: It is pretty hard to upgrade if you have a modifications in the core files, or in skin templates or you have an add-ons, which you should upgrade for new version too. Also you need the valid license key. May be it will be easier just to change the hosting. Also you can try to contact cs-cart team support.

Answer (score 0):

resolve with this :

downgrade server to php 5.3

-- OR --

open **addons/form_builder/func.php** and add **&** to all function

example:

find this   `function fn_form_builder_get_page_data($page_data)`
replace `function fn_form_builder_get_page_data(&$page_data)`